# PowerShell read IIS web application virtual directory without using directory credentials

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to use PowerShell to read Virtual Directories for our web apps on IIS. The snag is that if some virtual directories have INCORRECT log in credentials attached to them, PowerShell will still try and read the directory and after 3 tries will lock the user account. This is not what we want!

How can I make PowerShell use the script operator's login to iterate through virtual directories, and not trigger the lock out if the virtual directory credentials are incorrect?

My code is:

```
    $vdirs = Get-WebVirtualDirectory -Site $site_name
    foreach($virdir in $vdirs)
    {
        $webvdirectory2 = $virdir.path
        $virdir_name = $webvdirectory2.split("/")[-1]
        $out_line = "Web App`t{0} - IIS Site`t{1}`tVirtual Dirs`tName: {2}`tRelative Path: {3}`tAbsolute Path: {4}`t" -f $site_name , $app_name, $virdir_name , $virdir.path , $virdir.physicalPath         
        $out_line | out-file $outfile -Append
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like the root problem is about INCORRECT log in credentials attached to the virtual directories. What needs to be done to change that?

Comment: Agreed we need to correct those but we have a lot of servers so that will take time. What I am trying to do here is get an audit of what we have, then from that look further into the virtual directories.